# Html input completely ignoring overflow property

Tags: html, css, overflow

I need to put automatically displayed scroll to the input, when there more text than it can show and using `overflow: auto;` but it is not working and displayed as `overflow: hidden;`.
I've also tested every possible value in `overflow` property to
`<input type="text">` it is completely ignored, even `overflow: scroll` doesn't work and displayed as it is set to `hidden`.

Computed style in chrome is correct, it is **NOT** overriden by anything! But all works fine with `<textarea>`.

Is it normal behaviour or am i doing something wrong? If it is normal behaviour, are there other ways to set auto-scroll to the input?

**UPDATE:**
In empty html file with only input, when overflow set to value, where it should have scroll, it has some more height, when it shouldn't.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: are you trying to make the input box grow to accommodate your text? not sure what your are asking

Comment: You can't. `<input type="text">` cannot have a scrollbar. Ithink that the best you can do is faking it. Made an auto-resize (in width) `<input type="text">` and wrappit inside a div with scroll and fixed width

Answer (score 2):

`input[type=text]` is inherently displayed as `inline`, while textarea is a block level element, display `inline-block`. [`overflow` applies to block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

As a commenter points out, Firefox inherently `display`s input text elements as `inline`. So, to override that behavior, apply either `block` or `inline-block` to said input element.

Comment: This is browser dependet and according to the specs `input[type=text]` should be `inline-block`. Chrome defaults the display according to the specs, but Firefox uses `inline`.

Comment: Okay, good. So, to apply overflow to an inherently displayed inline element, explicitly apply `block` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

While @xandercoded gives you the right answer of what's going on I would like to provide a "solution" or workaround to achieve what I think the OP is trying to do.

As far as I know, you can't have scrollbar on an input field. But we can fake it in some ways.
What we can do is use javascript to make the input to grow automatically, and then put it inside a container with the `overflow:auto`. I'll give you an example:

### HTML:

```
  <div id="input-container">
    <input id="input" type="text"/>
  </div>
```

### CSS:

```
#input
{
  border: none; /* remove the border so we fake it better */
  outline: none; /* remove the outline so we fake it better */
}    
#input-container
{
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;  
}
```

### JS:

```
$('#input').autoGrowInput({ minWidth: 180, comfortZone: 10 });
```

For the js part, we use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [autoGrowInput](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-grow-input/demo.html) jquery plugin.

I made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvweyb7p/2/) with this.